# How can I have Monero historic price (USD) to download?

Tags: history

I´m having problems finding Monero historic prices in USD for my University project. Could someone advise me where to find this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the accepted answer here: 
https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/cryptocurrency-historical-prices

You would have to slightly modify it to get XMR rather than ETH, and then get a BTC v. USD data set over the same time period and figure it out, but I'm not sure there is a better way.

There's really not much price history pre-poloniex, except smooth's OTC thread on bitcointalk and TheKoziTwo's short-lived cryptonote exchange.